# PropType validation does not show warning in console

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, jsx

I am using React with ASP.NET and am trying to implement propType validation. But I don't receive any warnings even though the props I am passing to my component are clearly invalid:

```
var LoginBox = React.createClass({

    propTypes: {
        // the 'url' prop is not given and should result in a warning
        url: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        // given 'modalId' is a a string and should result in a warning as well
        modalId: React.PropTypes.bool
    },

    // some other functions ...

    render() { ... }
)};

ReactDOM.render(
    <LoginBox modalId="forgotModal"  loginUrl="/user/login" />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Am I not using the validation correctly?

Comment: Are you sure  you didn't miss something? Provided code seems to work fine https://jsfiddle.net/y0trd9e5/ -

Comment: The only difference I can see is that in the fsfiddle, it seems that Babel is also referenced. In my project I am just using `react-with-addons-15.2.1.min.js` and `react-dom-15.2.1.min.js`. Could this be the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using production version of react(`.min.js`), `propTypes` warning are disabled there.

Comment: Oh yes, that makes sense. I actually thought about switching to the developers version after solving this problem anyways. Thanks for your help!